# jQuery Post and IE8

Tags: jquery, post

This simple function doesn't work well in IE8:

```
function  load_ms(){
    $('#ll').html('loading');
    $.post('/w/a/i.php', {v:"r",lasaid:g_lid,spp:g_nis,p:gt},function(data) { 
        $('#items-c').html(data);
        $('div#ll').empty();
    });
}
```

This function is called by another function:

```
function  set_lid(lid){
    $('body').data('foo',lid);
    lasaid= $('body').data('foo');
    load_ms();
}
```

In IE8 the `load_ms()` function doesn't do its job every time I click on

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="set_lid(12)">go</a>
```

Sometimes the data is returned and sometimes not. I have to click many times.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?

Comment: Are you saying it _does_ work in other browsers (or other versions of IE)? Also, why does set_lid() store the lid parameter using both .data() _and_ the global variable lasaid?

Comment: It works in Fireworks and Chrome.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What error(s) does IE throw?

Comment: data are not returned, and the div#ll is always on top.

Comment: quick demo here http://dev3p.com/s_demo/